# Obj C - Autocomplete

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, autocomplete, textfield

Hey I got a problem with a tutorial I found for autocompletion: It says -

*Now, when the text in the text field has changed (ie: in the EditingChanged handler), just call the GetSuggestions method, which will return an array of strings that match the parameter passed*

```
NSArray *suggestions = [autocomplete GetSuggestions:textField.text];
```

*You can do whatever you want with these suggestions, I displayed them in  a table view and when the user taps a cell, the text is added to the text field ([source](http://www.radulucaciu.ro/iphone-autocomplete-class/5/))*

Well I placed the array in

```
...textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange...
```

but I cannot figure out how to 'call' the suggestions when I write something right behind my text somewhat like autocorrection :/ any thoughts?

tried something like

```
if ([textField.text length] > 0){
        ..somehow call suggestions

    }
```

but that just doesn't work :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a view to display them in. All you have done so far is load the autocomplete suggestions in an array.

You need to display them in a TableView or something. Look here to get a good tutorial on how they work. -> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Qbjwx0hB6A&list=SPE83F832121568D36&index=13

Take a good look at the source code provided by the author, he demonstrate how he use the array to populate a TableView.

Edit: The youtube tutorial is for a NSTableView for OS X programming, but you get the hang of it.